# Compare rows and replace value if there is a difference

Tags: r, loops

First of all: Happy New Year :)

I'm struggling with a loop so I'm now seeking your help.

Below is a short dummy:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("a","a","b","b","c","d"), type = c(1,1,2,2,3,4), area = c("a","b","a","a","b","b"), length = c(10), power = c(10, 100))
```

I'd like to compare each unique combination of `name`, `type` and `area`, and see if `length` and `power` vary or not. If they do not, I want to keep their value; if they do, I want to replace their value by 'Unknown'.
In the example above, there would thus only be a replacement for `name` = b: `length` would remain '10' but `power` would become 'Unknown'. As a result, the resulting dataframe would only have five rows.

That seems like a rather simple loop to come up with, but I haven't succeeded so far... do you have any idea?

Cheers,

Fred

Comment: Please Provide expected output in a  table format.

Comment: As a general suggestion, it may be better to replace these values with `NA` instead of `Unkown` if you want to use `power` in other calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need a for loop but can use `duplicated`.
First look up the rows that are have the same `name`, `type`, `area` and `length` but do not have the same power value. Replace one of the `power` values with `Unknown`

```
df[which(duplicated(df[1:4]) & !duplicated(df[1:5])),'power'] <- 'Unkown'
```

Next create a new dataframe that discards the other row

```
df2 <- df[which(!duplicated(df[1:4],fromLast = T)),]
```

Output:

```
> df2
  name type area length  power
1    a    1    a     10     10
2    a    1    b     10    100
4    b    2    a     10 Unkown
5    c    3    b     10     10
6    d    4    b     10    100
```

**EDIT**: Following additional requests from the OP here's a dplyr solution that works for more general cases.

```
# New dataframe; containing multiple duplicates
df3 <- data.frame(name = c("a","a","b","b","b","c","d"),
type = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,4), area = c("a","b","a","a","a","b","b"), 
length = rep(10,7), 
power = c(10, 100, 10, 100,100,10,100))


df3 %>% 
  group_by(name, type, area) %>% 
  mutate(length = ifelse(n() > 1 && var(length) != 0, "Unknown", paste0(length)),
    power = ifelse(n() > 1 && var(power) != 0, "Unknown", paste0(power)))
```

The function first groups by name, type and area. Next, it checks if there is more than 1 row, if this is true it checks if values vary, if both are true it replaces all values by "Unknown".

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   name, type, area [5]
  name   type area  length power  
  <fct> <dbl> <fct> <chr>  <chr>  
1 a         1 a     10     10     
2 a         1 b     10     100    
3 b         2 a     10     Unknown
4 b         2 a     10     Unknown
5 b         2 a     10     Unknown
6 c         3 b     10     10     
7 d         4 b     10     100
```

Comment: Thanks @Niek. I'll keep your example for something else, but tmfmnk's code below is more what I'm looking for.

Comment: You're welcome. As a small addition regarding your question for tmfmnk, by adding `df[which(duplicated(df[1:4], fromLast = T) & !duplicated(df[1:5], fromLast = T)),'power'] <- 'Unkown'` to the above code you should be able to modify both values to `Unkown`.

Comment: Thanks! It _almost_ does exactly what I need, but there is one tiny issue I didn't foresee... I use confidential data, so couldn't publish it here, but there are instances where there are more than 2 values to compare. I extracted & anonymized part of my real data ([https://github.com/fredlm/mockup/blob/master/duplicate.csv]) so you can see the issue. For `id` 6, I have 3 rows but only 2 options for e.g. `external_name` or `code`. As it stands, your code would not replace these 2 values by "Unknown"... Is there a way _not_ to compare to the 1st/last row, but just to any row in the combination?

Comment: Probably, but it drastically complicates things. One thing you could do is delete these lines (as your original question suggested) by creating the `df2` object as shown above. Or maybe add an additional step that changes values to `Unkown` if the case contains other `Unknown` values. I don't know immediately how to solve this, but will think about it later.

Comment: I've added a `dplyr` solution to the answer. You could expand on this by converting back to `data.frame` or add `,na.rm = T` so that calculation of the variance handles NA values. If you like the answer, could you accept it?

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr` you can do:

```
df %>%
 group_by(name, type, area) %>%
 mutate(length = ifelse(length != first(length), "Unknown", paste0(length)),
        power = ifelse(power != first(power), "Unknown", paste0(power)))

  name   type area  length power  
  <fct> <dbl> <fct> <chr>  <chr>  
1 a        1. a     10     10     
2 a        1. b     10     100    
3 b        2. a     10     10     
4 b        2. a     10     Unknown
5 c        3. b     10     10     
6 d        4. b     10     100
```

It checks whether the values are the same as for the first row for a given combination of "name", "type" and "area". If not, it fills the rows with "Unknown".

Comment: Thanks @tmfmnk! This looks very promising, but it's still not exactly what I'd need, as the `power` value in the third row should also be replaced by 'Unknown'. It could either be 10 or 100, so its value is 'Unknown', not the first one that shows up in the dataframe. Do you see what I mean? I'm not familiar with `dplyr`, but that looks quite powerful!
Cheers
ps: by the way I had called for `plyr` as well for another part of my script, which seemed to have prevented your bit from working properly